# Is there an implementation for pailliers algorithm for encrypton over string

Tags: python, python-2.7, cryptography, paillier

I have a database which consists of strings as well as numbers, I have to use homeomorphic scheme to encrypt fields. I am using Pailliers algorithm for the purpose, but I just find it for numbers or plain text as number, but not for any string. Can anyone please tell me if it is possible, or there is any algorithm as such to do that?

I am using python(phe library), but if you know of any other language which has library for this. It will be helpful.

Comment: A string is just a sequence of numbers, is it not?

Comment: yes, but I could not find any implementation that I can use it in python. I found one for number in `paillier` library but not for string

Comment: Ok. I got your point. Thanks anyway @ArtjomB. This was a dumb question.

Comment: Well, this is not a dumb question. I don't know whether it is secure to encrypt every character separately.